# Counting socket.io users across horizontal servers

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, scalability

I have multiple socket.io servers scaled horizontally using a redisstore.  I've got rooms setup effectively and am successfully able to broadcast to rooms across servers, etc.  Now I'm trying to build a status page and what I'm failing on figuring out is how to simply count the number of users connected across all servers.

io.sockets.clients('room') and io.sockets.sockets will only tell you the number of connected clients on that one server, not all servers connected to the same RedisStore.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just query each of the servers and add up the number of connected clients?

Comment: I too am looking for a way to answer this question, without having to set up some sort of watcher for it. FWIW though, it looks like the logic is that each server knows all of the clients connected to all servers - but may also have stale clients that disconnected from another server. It looks like socket.io didn't think it was worth the overhead of trimming stale clients on other servers, instead some servers will just broadcast to some voids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by having each server periodically set a user count in redis with an expiration that included their own pid:

every  do `setex userCount:<pid> <interval+10> <count>`

then the status server can query for each of these keys, and then get the values for each key:

for each `keys userCount*` do total+=`get <key>`

so if a server crashes or is shutdown then its counts will drop out of redis after interval+10

sorry about the ugly pseudocode. :)

Comment: How are you getting the count for each server's users?  The result of io.sockets.clients().length isn't always correct.

For example:

1. Process A is running and 2 clients connect.  io.sockets.clients().length will correctly return 2.
2. Start a new process, B, and connect 2 clients to it.  B will return 2, however A will now return 4 because it has subscribed to B's connection events.

Counts seem to get even more inaccurate when you try restarting a server and clients reconnect.

Comment: I'm using Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).length, but it seems to grow and not shrink accurately, perhaps for the same reasons you outline.  

So I had to hook into our presence system to get an accurate count.  For that, we save our user object to redis using socket.set and then update that object with activity or idleness.  So for the counting what I'm doing now is looping the sockets from io.sockets.sockets and if the user's presence state is 'active' then I add them to the count.

Answer (score 3):

When a user connects to the chatroom, you can atomically increment a user counter in your RedisStore.  When a user disconnects, you decrement the value.  This way Redis maintains the user count and is accessible to all servers.

See [INCR](http://redis.io/commands/incr) and [DECR](http://redis.io/commands/decr)

```
SET userCount = "0"
```

When a user connects:

```
INCR userCount
```

When a user disconnects:

```
DECR userCount
```

Comment: except if a server crashes, then those counts become meaningless

Comment: You could maintain a separate count for each server and sum them up.  If a server goes down you set that server's counter to 0.

Comment: that would require a separate process that is keeping track of servers and fixing counts for them.  I was really hoping there was a purely socket.io method of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it using Redis scripting. It requires version 2.6 or later, so most likely still requires compiling your own instance for now.

Each time a process starts up, I generate a new UUID and leave it in the global scope. I could use the pid, but this feels a little safer.

```
# Pardon my coffeescript
processId = require('node-uuid').v4()
```

When a user connects (the socket.io connection event), I then push that user's id into a list of users based on that processId.  I also set the expiry of that key to 30 seconds.

```
RedisClient.lpush "process:#{processId}", user._id
RedisClient.expire "process:#{processId}", 30
```

When a user disconnects (the disconnect event), I remove it and update the expiry.

```
RedisClient.lrem "process:#{processId}", 1, user._id
RedisClient.expire "process:#{processId}", 30
```

I also setup an function that runs on a 30 second interval to essentially "ping" that key so that it stays there.  So if the process does accidentally die, all those user sessions will essentially disappear.

```
setInterval ->
  RedisClient.expire "process:#{processId}", 30
, 30 * 1000
```

Now for the magic. Redis 2.6 includes LUA scripting, which essentially gives a stored procedure sort of functionality. It's really fast and not very processor intensive (they compare it to "almost" running C code).

My stored procedure basically loops through all of the process lists, and creates a user:user_id key with their total count of current logins. This means that if they're logged in with two browsers, etc. it'll still allow me to use logic to tell if they've disconnected completely, or just one of their sessions.

I run this function every 15 seconds on all my processes, and also after a connect/disconnect event. This means that my user counts will most likely be accurate to the second, and never incorrect for more than 15 to 30 seconds.

The code to generate that redis function looks like:

```
def = require("promised-io/promise").Deferred

reconcileSha = ->
  reconcileFunction = "
    local keys_to_remove = redis.call('KEYS', 'user:*')
    for i=1, #keys_to_remove do
      redis.call('DEL', keys_to_remove[i])
    end

    local processes = redis.call('KEYS', 'process:*')
    for i=1, #processes do
      local users_in_process = redis.call('LRANGE', processes[i], 0, -1)
      for j=1, #users_in_process do
        redis.call('INCR', 'user:' .. users_in_process[j])
      end
    end
  "

  dfd = new def()
  RedisClient.script 'load', reconcileFunction, (err, res) ->
    dfd.resolve(res)
  dfd.promise
```

And then I can use that in my script later on with:

```
reconcileSha().then (sha) ->
  RedisClient.evalsha sha, 0, (err, res) ->
    # do stuff
```

The last thing I do is try and handle some shutdown events to make sure that the process tries it's best to not rely on the redis timeouts and actually shuts down gracefully.

```
gracefulShutdown = (callback) ->
  console.log "shutdown"
  reconcileSha().then (sha) ->
    RedisClient.del("process:#{processId}")
    RedisClient.evalsha sha, 0, (err, res) ->
      callback() if callback?

# For ctrl-c
process.once 'SIGINT', ->
  gracefulShutdown ->
    process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGINT')

# For nodemon
process.once 'SIGUSR2', ->
  gracefulShutdown ->
    process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2')
```

So far it's been working great.

One thing I still want to do is make it so that the redis function returns any keys that have changed their values. This way I could actually send out an event if the counts have changed for a particular user without any of the servers actively knowing (like if a process dies). For now, I have to rely on polling the user:* values again to know that it's changed. It works, but it could be better...

Comment: That's an interesting implementation. Do you worry about the cost of the 30 second ping if you have 10k+ clients connected?

Comment: Not really. It hasn't been tested to that extent yet. Redis is becoming the most important secondary component in my app, so that server will get the resources necessary to keep it going. If I can see that the application instances aren't crashing very much, I may take another approach that isn't so costly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hash keys to store the values.

When a user connects to server 1 you could set a field called "srv1" on a key called "userCounts".  Just override the value to whatever the current count is using [HSET](http://redis.io/commands/hset).  No need to increment/decrement.  Just set the current value known by socket.io.

```
HSET userCounts srv1 "5"
```

When another user connects to a different server set a different field.

```
HSET userCounts srv2 "10"
```

Then any server can get the total by returning all the fields from "userCounts" and adding them together using [HVALS](http://redis.io/commands/hvals) to return a value list.

```
HVALS userCounts
```

When a server crashes you'll need to run a script in response to the crash that removes that server's field from userCounts or HSET it to "0".

You can look at [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to automate restarting the server.

Comment: I use upstart to restart servers, which works a lot better than forever (which I've dug into quite a bit). I'm trying to account for a complete server failure, which does happen from time to time.  I do have monitoring for that (zabbix), but getting zabbix to inform the dashboard when a server goes down seems like quite a hack to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, expiration is only available on keys and not individual hset fields.  But maybe you can work something out with a combination of keys and fields.

Comment: I think my plan now is to use 
`setex userCounts:<server-pid> <timeout> <count>`
and then the status server can call `keys userCounts*` and then get and add up those keys.  Since they expire, if a server crashes its counts will fall off.