# Count online users node.js socket.io cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to keep a counter of the online users on multi-process (cluster) nodejs app that is using socket.io for real-time communication.

The problem is I cannot use the recommended method:

```
var onlineCount = Object.keys(io.manager.connected).length;
```

because I am using the cluster functionality so this isn't shared between worker instances. I have tried using the below approach but the counter is still not right:

```
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
      redis.incr('connected').then(function(cnt) {
          io.broadcast('count', cnt);
      });
      socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redis.decr('connected').then(function(cnt) {
            io.broadcast('count', cnt);
        });
      });
    });
```

Is there any suggested approach because I have googled it and found nothing useful.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like this might be a good solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12267260/3439038